# Alternatives for a relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

I wrote:

> 1) The action part specifies the label or the class **that is assigned** to the matching node (e.g. content, noise)

Can I write the relative clause in the following forms? If yes, which of these three options are better?

> 2) The action part specifies the label or the class **to be assigned to** the matching node (e.g. content, noise)
>
> 3) The action part specifies the label or the class **to assign** the matching node (e.g. content, noise)
>
> 4) The action part specifies the label or the class **of** the matching node (e.g. content, noise)

Comment: Not clear what "the action part" means, but "to be assigned" is clear.

Comment: @TRomano I divided a rule into two parts: C -> A, the condition(al) part and the action part. when the condition is met, the action is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that #1 expresses your intended meaning:

> 2) The action part specifies the label or the class **to be assigned to** the matching node (e.g. content, noise)

This differs from #1 only in that it implied the label has *not yet been assigned*, whereas #1 implies that it has. This fine distinction might not matter to you or your audience.

> 3) The action part specifies the label or the class **to assign** the matching node (e.g. content, noise)

Without "to", it's not clear what is being assigned to what. Again, this might not make a real difference, as the label and node are assigned *to each other* (or are they? they are mutually associated, but If "assign" is a one-way relation, you'd better specify the direction!)

> 4) The action part specifies the label or the class **of** the matching node (e.g. content, noise)

Now you've eliminated the concept of **assigning**.  Maybe *specifies* is a good stand-in for **assign**, but if I wanted it to be taken that way, I would say

- "...specifies the (x) **for** (y)", 
  rather than
- "...specifies the (x) **of** (y)."